# Comparing variables in a Batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to extract a string from a .txt file and compare that string to another string.

This specific scenario requires that I do an action if an SFC scan did not detect any problems.

This is what I currently have:

```
@echo off

Setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%a in ('find /n /v "" ^< "C:\kworking\SFC_Scans\SFC_Logs\SFC_Log.txt" ^| findstr "Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations." ') do set "string=%%b"

set string2=Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.

if !string! EQU !string2! (echo Equal) else if  !string! NEQ !string2! (echo Not Equal)
```

The SFC_Log.txt file contains the text "Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations." So, the output I should get is "Equal," but I instead get "Not Equal," and I cannot figure out why.

I don't know if this is an issue with how my variables are being generated or if I am comparing them incorrectly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You know that (as you use it), `findstr` returns every line that contains even one of the words? And why employ a `for` loop? `find "Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations." "C:\kworking\SFC_Scans\SFC_Logs\SFC_Log.txt" && echo yes || echo no`

Comment: Honestly, I am learning as I go. What I know is using findstr alone gives me problems when using this batch file to scan through SFC scans that did detect problems. The for loop gives me the ability to get just the text I am looking for

Comment: Regardless that @Stephan has offered a much simpler method; you should use `If /I "%string%" == "%string2%" (Echo Equal) Else Echo Not Equal` instead of `if !string! EQU !string2! (echo Equal) else if  !string! NEQ !string2! (echo Not Equal)`. As you can see, you do not need delayed expansion at all, so should probably change it to `DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION`, or simply remove it.

Comment: Because of the way the for loop iterates through the .txt file, ```%string%``` will be set to the value of all text in the .txt file. Because of this, I need to use ```!string!``` in order to single out a specific line.

Comment: No @jhamlin, `%string%` in your code will be set to the complete content of last line in `C:\kworking\SFC_Scans\SFC_Logs\SFC_Log.txt`, which contained one or more of the case sensitive strings, `Windows`, `Resource`, `Protection`, `did`, `not`, `find`, `any`, `integrity`, or `violations.`, where the latter ends with an unnecessary wildcard character, **`.`**, _(meaning one or no characters)_. Once the variable `string` is defined, it is not modified within any parenthesized or code block, and therefore does not require delayed expansion to be enabled.

Comment: @Compo, that is how it works using ```findstr```, but I am using that very convoluted for loop to iterate through the file. The reason I am using the for loop is because the SFC_Log.txt file is not constant.

Comment: I need to be able to run an SFC remotely on 600 computers. The SFC scan will generate an output to the SFC_Log.txt file. I need to generate a report if the SFC scan was not able to complete repairs if they were needed. However, before I get to that point, I need to be able to differentiate between a scan that didn't find problems, a scan that found and fixed problems, and a scan that found and could not fix problems. Using ```findstr``` will not work because the output messages are too similar between the 3 reports, and I will receive false positives.

Comment: @jhamlin, your `For` command first used `find.exe` to grab every line within `C:\kworking\SFC_Scans\SFC_Logs\SFC_Log.txt`, including empty ones, and prefixes each with its line number, _(within square brackets)_. It then pipes each of those to `findstr.exe` which does exactly what I've already told you it does. Then because you've delimited using the first closing square bracket, the returned variable will be the entire line content of the last line containing one of those matches. BTW, when you use `sfc.exe` its results are saved to `%SystemRoot%\logs\cbs\cbs.log` each identified by `[SR]`.

Comment: @Compo, like I said earlier, I am learning as I go, so that is very useful information, and I appreciate it. Using ```for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%a in ('find /n /v "" ^< "C:\kworking\SFC_Scans\SFC_Logs\SFC_Log.txt" ^| findstr "Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations." ') do set "string=%%b"``` works for what I need it to do. I am simply asking about the comparator statements. The variables have the correct information in them, so I don't know why their comparison isn't working.  ```cbs.log``` contains a bunch of nonsense that makes things difficult.

Comment: I told you, in my comment, how to perform the comparison, about an hour and forty minutes ago! BTW, I'm not sure what exactly creates your log file, but if I was creating one myself I'd use, `@%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /L /C:"[SR] Repairing " /C:"[SR] Cannot repair " /C:"[SR] Repaired " %SystemRoot%\logs\cbs\cbs.log 1>"SFC_Log.txt"`, to see every line where something required doing during an SFC run, and all of those should have details, including date and time, the relative files etc.

Comment: If your code is defining the variable you wanted, then that is simply due to luck, rather than you having used appropriate code! If you open a Command Prompt window, type `find /? & findstr /?`, and press the `[ENTER]` key, you should get sufficient information to show you how both of those commands work, and confirm what both Stephan and I have told you.

Comment: @Compo, I hadn't worked on this in a week. But I was able to get it working. I ended up using ```find``` instead of that silly ```for``` loop.  From there, the issue was with how I was calling the variables in the ```if``` statement. I needed to put quotes around the variables because they are string type variables. After that, it worked exactly as needed. I didn't even know about ```find``` before our conversation. I just thought there was ```findstr``` lol. Everyone (including you and Stephan) just says to use ```findstr``` for what I am doing, and that just doesn't work for what I needed.

Comment: But I would like you thank you for introducing me to ```find```.  You are right. It is much simpler and easier to work with than the ```for``` loop I was using. The ```for``` loop just worked for the time being, so I saw no need in changing it. I also didn't need a way to reference the ```cbs.log``` file. I only needed to run ```sfc /scannow >SFC_Log.txt``` to generate a sudo log file because, for the time being, I don't care about what needed fixed or anything like that. I just needed the generic ```SFC``` output.